# Computer science map and exclude

Tags: functional-programming, terminology

I have an array with some values:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I'd like to make a new array that contains `mapped` version of the items in the array above, but only add them to the new array if they pass a truth test.

A combination of map and filter?

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].mapFilter(function(n) { if (n > 2) return n * 3 })
```

What is this called?

Comment: Perhaps called "filter-out" ?

Comment: A projection with filter?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, wouldn't `filter-out` just be `reject`? And `reject` has no mapping capability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is map composed with filter. It doesn't need a name.

```
map (*3) . filter (>2)
```